# Нужно сохранить данные а потом сразу их брать, так чтоб не грузить память системы

Tags: python, txt

Сохраняются числа в txt файл и берутся от туда же.

```py
file = open('stock.txt', 'a+')
file.write('0.0167\n')
file.seek(0)
```

Но при этом притормаживает система.
Как избежать txt. файла и ускорить процесс чтения, для вывода информации? Какие способы сохранения данных есть в python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос рабочий тест, скорость которого можно измерить. Сейчас код не полный и где он может тормозить никому не ведомо.

Comment: mmap почитаю, спасибо. Забыл указать в коде index = 0, начало отсчета. Здесь загвоздка в том, что после запуска программы, идет накопление чисел в txt файле, минута...пять...десять и чем больше информации накапливается, тем дольше выводится информация, например нужно вывести общую сумму чисел, накопленные за пять минут работы программы, если через минуту вызвать то сразу будет результат, через 5 минут, уже думает секунд 8, через 10 минут еще дольше ждешь. Вот я и хочу узнать, есть ли способ накопить эти числа где то еще и потом сразу прочесть без задержек, даже через три часа или больше?

Comment: а сколько ваших чисел ? каков размер тхт?

Comment: Повторяюсь: код в вопрос. Это не лечение запоя по фотографии. Есть код - есть о чём говорить. Нет кода - нет проблемы.

Comment: Код слишком большой, не помещается, плюс к нему привязан видеофайл и txt. Но смысл то понятен, мне не нужно готовое здесь решение, просто, если кто знает скажите где найти инфу, что почитать. Я только учусь, как вы когда то, поэтому буду признателен просто за инфу, а там сам справлюсь. Спасибо.

Comment: Кроме txt, exel и т.п негде это сделать?

Comment: шар слишком мутный. видно что ошибка  у вас  371й строчке